# In tomcat 8, are web application dependencies (/WEB-INF/lib) in-scope for provided dependencies?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, dependency-management, tomcat8

I'm trying to install hbase/hadoop drivers as `provided` in my web application.

This procedure works in Websphere using a "shared library" reference, so this seems to be tomcat-specific.  Tomcat 8.0.x and 8.5.x, Java 8.

From `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

One class initializes an hbase object in a static initializer:

```
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

static {
    ClassLoader classLoader = SimpleServlet.class.getClassLoader();
    URL[] urLs = ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs();
    LOGGER.info("SimpleServlet.class: " + Arrays.asList(urLs));
    while(classLoader.getParent() != null) {
        classLoader = classLoader.getParent();
        urLs = ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs();
        LOGGER.info("parent: " + Arrays.asList(urLs));
    }

    classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    urLs = ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs();
    LOGGER.info("context: " + Arrays.asList(urLs));
    while(classLoader.getParent() != null) {
        classLoader = classLoader.getParent();
        urLs = ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs();
        LOGGER.info("parent: " + Arrays.asList(urLs));
    }
}

    private static Configuration hbaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    ...
}
```

My provided deps are installed in [the usual way](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html):

```
$ ls -l ../tomcat/8.5.8/libexec/lib/
...
-rw-r--r--   1 ...  3429485 Aug 13 14:54 hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 ...   530078 Aug 13 14:55 hbase-common-1.1.2.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 ...    61829 Aug 13 14:56 commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

The war looks as expected:

```
$ jar tf .../target/sandbox-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/com/
WEB-INF/classes/com/example/
WEB-INF/classes/webapp/
WEB-INF/classes/webapp/WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/lib/
WEB-INF/classes/com/example/SimpleServlet.class
WEB-INF/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar  // <-- here it is
WEB-INF/web.xml
...
```

The hbase static method uses guava in a constructor somewhere internally and the web application fails on deployment:

```
13-Aug-2017 20:19:37.680 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [simpleServlet] in web application [] threw load() exception
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Preconditions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta.<init>(Configuration.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta.<init>(Configuration.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:423)
    at com.example.SimpleServlet.<clinit>(SimpleServlet.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1050)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5223)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If guava is added to the shared libs directory, then the provided dependency sees it.

guava is on the classpath output by in the static initializer prior to the static method, and the shared libs are visible in the parents, as expected:

```
[RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.example.SimpleServlet - SimpleServlet.class: [file:.../webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/, file:.../webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar, ...]
[RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.example.SimpleServlet - parent: [..., .../lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar, .../lib/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar, .../lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.jar, ...], ...
[RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.example.SimpleServlet - context: [file:.../webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/, file:.../webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar, ...]
[RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO com.example.SimpleServlet - parent: [..., .../lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar, .../lib/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar, .../lib/hbase-common-1.1.2.jar, ...], ...
```

Why is guava not visible to the provided dependencies?

Comment: All Java EE app servers use a hierarchy of class loaders: bootstrap, app server, application.  If the app server class loader has a dependency that is only satisfied by the application app server it will throw an exception.  You may have to put all the dependencies for those JARs at the app server level in the Tomcat /lib folder.

Comment: suppose guava references needs to added to Tomcat/lib folder

Comment: @duffymo I hear you regarding the hierarchy; but in this case the class calling the static method is in the web app's classloader, as evidenced by the classloader outputs.  If a class loads a class found in a parent classloader (the app server common, in this case) does it no longer have access to the child classloaders? I'd also like to know why this problem doesn't occur on Websphere.

Comment: WebSphere != Tomcat.  Parents would not know about children.

Comment: I've learned that you can reverse the order of classloading in tomcat with a `<Loader delegate="true"/>` in the webapp `Context` configuration.  This should make tomcat behave like websphere, but the problem above persists.  I've also asked a related question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677748/why-doesnt-activating-the-delegating-classloader-in-tomcat-change-the-apparent